# Is there a program that can send data via sockets to a server, to test it?

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, webserver

I have a simple socket server, that waits for a message and responds. How can I test this? Is there a client app or something that can help me send some data on a specific port to a server, and see the output? Telnet?

Comment: What OS do you want to run it on?

Comment: Windows XP? That's what I'm working on right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple telnet client works well for such tests. You can also try PuTTY in either Telnet or Raw connection modes. Both allow you to choose the port you want to connect to.

Also a tool like [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en) is pretty useful to analyse the protocol's data flow if you don't have direct control (by logs) on what's being sent over the wire.

Answer (score 6):

netcat should be able to handle anything you need to do with socket testing.

http://pctechtips.org/netcat-the-swiss-army-knife-useful-commands/#more-103

Answer (score 2):

Windump - tcpdump works well, and has binaries available to Windows

Answer (score 1):

You have several choices:

1) You can use Chrome or FireFox plugins such as:

- [Simple WebSocket Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-websocket-client/pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo/related?hl=en)
- [Smart WebSocket Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smart-websocket-client/omalebghpgejjiaoknljcfmglgbpocdp)

2) You can use `WebSocket` or [`ReconnectingWebSocket`](https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket) in JavaScript. this is a simple test with `WebSocket`:

- Open Chrome browser
- Press `F12` or `Right Click on page then click Inspect Element` to open developer console
- You shoud see a window with several tabs. Go to `console` tab then write this code.

`ws = new WebSocket('ws://<YOUR-DOMAIN>:<PORT>')`

`ws.send('STH YOU WANT TO SEND')`

3) You can use `websocket-client`. It is a simple python library. You must install `python` and `pip`, then `websocket-client` via pip. This is a simple example:

Go to python shell and type.

```
from websocket import WebSocket
ws = WebSocket()
ws.connect('ws://<YOUR-DOMAIN>:<PORT>')
ws.send('STH YOU WANT TO SEND')
```

Answer (score 0):

hit the command line, and just use telnet.

if you have a simple echo server, go to town.